# ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to upload images.
The upload is working fine and is getting uploaded under media folder.

But I am unable to make the media links browsable. It says `Error 404`.

To make them browsable these are the changes that I made.

1. In **settings.py** I added the following lines.

   `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

   `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

   `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   STATIC_URL = '/media/'`
2. In **url.py** I added the following lines

   `if settings.DEBUG is True:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

`DEBUG` is `True` in `settings.py` as it's not in production. It is on my local machine under development.

But when I am starting the server it is showing me the following error:-

```
ImproperlyConfigured :- Empty static prefix not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys! I found my own mistake. Instead of MEDIA_URL I was using STATIC_URL